# Can someone help me read this stat concerning "distinct miners"?

Tags: network, miner, statistics

Scrolling on https://etherchain.org/ , I was looking at "distinct miners" statistics( https://stats.etherchain.org/dashboard/db/distinct-miners ).

I just can't figure out what it shows concerning the network. It's expressed as a percentage, but what does it say?

Comment: It's not a percentage but the number of discinct miners in the last 24 hours, e.g., how many different accounts mined a block in 24 hours.

Comment: ok, but it's not clear on the graph. Where did you find the info that it is in the last 24h? (so that I will find things by myself next time :) :) ) Thks

Comment: 1 Data point in 24h lets me assume it is. I agree it's not well described.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And it is in line with this : https://etherchain.org/statistics/miners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's not well described. One data point in 24 hours lets me assume it is the daily count of distinct miners.

So, it's not a percentage but the number of discinct miners in the last 24 hours, e.g., how many different accounts mined a block in 24 hours.